# How to configure the word break on Intellij terminal for Opt+Backspace

Tags: terminal, keyboard, zsh

When I press <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> within Intellij (Goland) terminal using zsh in macOS, it deletes the words until it encounters a word separator like a period, space, comma, or a dash.

How do I configure it to only consider space as a word separator, i.e. delete everything until the next space?

Example: `ls ./foo/bar.txt` (caret at the end)

Current behavior: `ls ./foo/bar`.

Wanted behavior: `ls`